# Unable to resolve module ../../../component-updater error in react-native-calendars upgrade from 1.222.0 to 1.1274.0 version

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm trying to upgrade the react-native-calendar package from 0.222.1 to 0.1274.1 the latest version in my react-native project.
[versions link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendars)

In v1.222.0, the file was named react-native-calendars/src/component-updater.ts
In v1.1274.0, the file has been renamed to camelcase as react-native-calendars/src/componentUpdater.ts

[repo lonk](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/blob/master/src/componentUpdater.ts)

I cleared the node_modules and deleted the package-lock.json and then did npm i.

My react-native is v0.66.4.

But I keep getting this error -

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module ../../../component-updater from C:\terminal-visits\node_modules\react-native-calendars\src\calendar\day\basic\index.js:

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\react-native-calendars\src\component-updater(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.svg|.native.svg|.svg)
  * node_modules\react-native-calendars\src\component-updater\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.svg|.native.svg|.svg)
> 1 | import values from 'lodash/values';
  2 | import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  3 | import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
  4 | import { TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\terminal-visits\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:107:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\terminal-visits\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:288:43)
    at Object.resolve (C:\terminal-visits\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (C:\terminal-visits\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at C:\terminal-visits\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\terminal-visits\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (C:\terminal-visits\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at async addDependency (C:\terminal-visits\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 5)
```

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: This looks like a cache issue. Try this 1: **cd android && ./gradlew clean** 2: **cd ../** 3: **rm -rf node_modules** 4: **npm cache clean --force** 5: **npm install** 6: **npm start -- --reset-cache** 7: **npx react-native run-android**

Comment: @AkshayShenoy Yes, it works now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, this looks like a cache issue.
Try this 
1: **cd android && ./gradlew clean** 
2: **cd ../**
3: **rm -rf node_modules**
4: **npm cache clean --force** 
5: **npm install** 
6: **npm start -- --reset-cache** 
7: **npx react-native run-android**